# how to make my horizontal histogram to vertical

Tags: python, text-formatting

this is a part of my program which generates * patterns from 4 user inputs

```
total= progresscount + trailercount + retrivercount + excludecount
print("....................................................")
print("Histogram")
print("Progress",progresscount,":" , "*" * progresscount)                                
print("Trailer",trailercount,":" , "*" * trailercount)                                      
print("Retriver",retrivercount,":" , "*" * retrivercount)                                    
print("Excluded",excludecount ,":" , "*" * excludecount )                                
print("....................................................")
```

if I run my whole program and enter 2 3 1 and 2 for each input requests, output looks like this

```
....................................................
Histogram
Progress 2 : **
Trailer 3 :  ***
Retriver 1 : *
Excluded 2 : ** 
.................................................... 

and I want to make a vertical version like this

....................................................
Progress Trailing Retriever Excluded 
   *        *        *          * 
   *        *                   *
            * 
....................................................
```

help me to figure this out?

Comment: You need to do a lot of alignment with tabs.  If this isn't a one-off thing that you are doing, I suggest you look at the library [`rich`](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function like below:

```
def display_vhist(data):
    cell_len = max([len(k) for k in data]) + 2
    max_val = max(data.values())

    # display header
    print(*[h.center(cell_len) for h in data.keys()], sep='')

    # display histogram
    for i in range(1, max_val+1):
        for v in data.values():
            c = '*' if i <= v else ' '
            print(c.center(cell_len), end='')
        print()
```

Usage:

```
data = {'Progress': 2, 'Trailer': 3, 'Retriver': 1, 'Excluded': 1}
display_vhist(data)

# Output

 Progress  Trailer   Retriver  Excluded 
    *         *         *         *     
    *         *                         
              *
```

Comment: nice thanks this is useful. can I do this with maybe tab spacing and something like that? and can u help me out if u dont mind. thanks again...

Comment: I strongly discourage you to use tabulations. Each display terminal uses as much space as it wants so you run the risk of having a bad display.